# Can only echo message witin tags that include array

Tags: php, pdo

So my issue is I can only echo `$nf` witin the php tags, where the array is located. If  I try to do

```
 <?php
    $posts = array();
    while(($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false){
        $posts[] =  array(
        'post_content' => $row['post_content'],
        'likes' => $row['post_likes'],
        'time' => $row['post_date'], 
        'id' => $row['id']     
    );
        }   


    ?>
    <? if(count($posts) < 1){
        $nf = 'No posts, Yet.';
    }

?>
<?php

echo $nf;
?>
```

This won't work, but if I echo it in between the other tags it will. I'm not really sure what to do. Any help would be great.

Comment: you aren't setting `$nf` if `$posts` is not empty. You are only setting it if `count($posts) < 1`.

Comment: because you probably have `short_open_tags` disabled, your `if()` statement is just inside `<?`, which won't trigger the php engine.

Comment: Nope, they are enabled. @MarcB

Comment: So add an else statement? Not sure how that would help though @JonathanKuhn

Comment: Also break down while loop condition ..$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) && $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false

Comment: I get `syntax error, unexpected '!==' (T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL)` @Bhushya

Comment: Oh sorry can u try remove sexond condition && $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false and what is result when u puts else

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying it does not work with short tags then you will need to enabled that.

Otherwise you can always stick to the standard tags `<?php ...?>` which is the preferred way to avoid situation like the one you have where it is not enabled on the server.

This can break code when moving to different servers, better stay with standard.